# Play on linux "Cannot set locale to " " error

Tags: wine, playonlinux, locale

Can someone, please help me to fix this error. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It could be due to conflicting languages set as per this discussion. http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-8963.html The admin provides a solution for forcing Play on Linux to run in English.

Comment: Seeing as it fixed your problem I'll post it as an answer. This will help anyone in the future if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-8963.html) on the Play On Linux forums, this error can be caused by having different languages set for the `LANG` and `LC_*` variables.
You can check these variables by typing `locale` into the Terminal.

A solution for this is to force Play On Linux to run in English.

This can be achieved by running this command in the Terminal:

```
LC_ALL=C playonlinux
```

More information on the `LC_ALL` command can be [found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763).